# How to add text before/to the left of \begin{lstlisting}?

Tags: listings

I want to write exercises where the student must explain numbered pieces of code. To the left of each piece of code, I would like to add a letter, like a), or a number.

I prefer to use

```
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none]
some code
\end{lstlisting}
```

(with all the styles I have defined) and not `\lstinline`.

Can that be done in a simple way? (I could not find it in the lstlisting manual or using google.)

In the example shown the text is not on the same line but on the line before.
My LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{
language=Python,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\tiny, 
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt, 
tabsize=4,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
commentstyle=\color{Red},   
stringstyle=\color{PineGreen},
frame=none,                    
columns=fullflexible,
keepspaces=true,
xleftmargin=\parindent,
showstringspaces=false,
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Exercise 1. Explain the output in each case:

\noindent a) \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none]
print("Horse"[2])
\end{lstlisting}
\noindent b) \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none]
print("Donkey"[1:-1])
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{
language=Python,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
tabsize=4,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
commentstyle=\color{Red},
stringstyle=\color{PineGreen},
frame=none,
columns=fullflexible,
keepspaces=true,
xleftmargin=\parindent,
showstringspaces=false,
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\noindent Exercise 1. Explain the output in each case:

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),align=left]

\item 
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none]
print("Horse"[2])
\end{lstlisting}

\item  
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none]
print("Donkey"[1:-1])
\end{lstlisting}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a simple and useful solution.